# Invoking the window based application by QTP

Tags: qtp

Issue in invoking the window based application by QTP
 When we invoke our application using QTP, the system hangs and the application not loads
 the memory size of the application, shown in the Task Manager is 350 MB
 My script is in qc and i am executing script from qc. qc automatically launches qtp
 The script tries to load the appliaction under test but it fails.
 Double click on the exe of AUT. login screen is displayed. enter user name and password in the login window and application should load but instaed of loading the application system hangs.

Manually (when QTP is not opened) application loads properly
 but when QTP is already opened application is not loaded (either manually or by QTP).
 Please suggest some way to launch the application when QTP is already opened
 this problem is due to memory size. is there any way by which memory size of either QTP or the application is reduced (while launching the application), so that application can load properly.

Comment: How much total memory does the system running QTP have available to it?

Comment: Memory size should not be an issue these days or you must be running on a 8 year old mid-end system; 350 MB for an application seems quite normal, especially in Vista or higher where Windows will consume as much memory as it can. I think the problem resides somewhere else where the QTP-hook blocks (software) resources to your application so it could not startup properly.

Comment: HI, the machine RAM is 12GB, Win 7 OS and the application is windows based .net 4, wpf applictaion. when qtp is already opened, application (AUT) is not launched either manually or by script (only blank screen is displayed).

Answer (score 0):

You could make QTP run in background that may reduce the memory consumption.

```
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
qtApp.Launch
qtApp.Visible = False
```

I am not sure but you can give this method a shot.

Thanks